# command set extension not visible in Ie11

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, pnp-js-core, ie-11

Hi i created spfx command set extension but its not visible in IE11 other browser is visible and working.
Used import "@pnp/polyfill-ie11"; as well but no luck , do i missing any configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a defect of IE itself

Being an old browser, IE 11 lacks a few features like fetch, map, and proxy. During SPFx development we normally make use of these features and they fail to work in IE 11.

Please see if the article below is helpful to you:

[IE 11 Polyfill Package For SPFx](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ie-11-polyfill-package-for-spfx/)